# Pandas v1.1.0: Groupby rolling count slower than rolling mean & sum

Tags: python, pandas

I am running a groupby rolling count, sum & mean using Pandas v1.1.0 and I notice that the rolling count is considerably slower than the rolling mean & sum. This seems counter intuitive as we can derive the count from the mean and sum and save time. Is this a bug or am I missing something? Grateful for advice.

```
import pandas as pd

# Generate sample df
df = pd.DataFrame({'column1': range(600), 'group': 5*['l'+str(i) for i in range(120)]})

# sort by group for easy/efficient joining of new columns to df
df=df.sort_values('group',kind='mergesort').reset_index(drop=True)

# timing of groupby rolling count, sum and mean
%timeit df['mean']=df.groupby('group').rolling(3,min_periods=1)['column1'].mean().values
%timeit df['sum']=df.groupby('group').rolling(3,min_periods=1)['column1'].sum().values
%timeit df['count']=df.groupby('group').rolling(3,min_periods=1)['column1'].count().values

### Output
6.14 ms ± 812 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
5.61 ms ± 179 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
76.1 ms ± 4.78 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

### df Output for illustration
print(df.head(10))

   column1 group   mean     sum  count
0        0    l0    0.0     0.0    1.0
1      120    l0   60.0   120.0    2.0
2      240    l0  120.0   360.0    3.0
3      360    l0  240.0   720.0    3.0
4      480    l0  360.0  1080.0    3.0
5        1    l1    1.0     1.0    1.0
6      121    l1   61.0   122.0    2.0
7      241    l1  121.0   363.0    3.0
8      361    l1  241.0   723.0    3.0
9      481    l1  361.0  1083.0    3.0
```

Comment: This looks like a bug to me and is definitely worth opening a ticket for on GitHub.

Comment: Thanks. I've opened the ticket. https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/35625

Answer (score 1):

**Did you really mean `count` (number of non-NaN values)?** That can not be inferred from just `sum` and `mean`.

I suspect that what you are looking for would be a `size` operator (just the length of the group, irrespective of whether or not there are any NaNs). While `size` exists in regular `groupby`, it seems that it is absent in `RollingGroupBy` (at least as of pandas 1.1.4). One can calculate the size of the rolling groups with:

```
# DRY:
rgb = df.groupby('group').rolling(3, min_periods=1)['column1']

# size is either:
rgb.apply(len)

# or
rgb.apply(lambda g: g.shape[0])
```

Neither of those two is as fast as it could, of course, because there needs to be a call to the function for each group, rather than being all vectorized and working just off of the rolling window indices `start` and `end`. On my system, either of the above is 2x slower than `rgb.sum()` or `rgb.mean()`.

Thinking about how one would implement `size`: it is obvious (just `end - start` for each window).

Now, in the case one *really* wanted to speed up `count` (count of non-NaN values): one could establish a "cumulative count" at first:

```
cumcnt = (1 - df['column1'].isnull()).cumsum()
```

(this is very fast, about 200x faster than `rgb.mean()` on my system).

Then the rolling function could simply take `cumcnt[end] - cumcnt[start]`.

I don't know enough about the internals of `RollingGroupBy` (and their use of various `mixin`s) to assess feasibility, but at least functionally it seems pretty straightforward.

**Update:**

It seems that the issue is already fixed with [these commits](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/36872/commits). That was fast and simple --I am impressed with the internal architecture of pandas and all the tools they already have on their Swiss army knife!